# The Ricci curvature is bounded below by scalar curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curvature, tensor, ricci-flow, ricci-curvature

So I have more questions coming from Dr Hamilton's "Three-Manifolds with Positive Ricci Curvature" paper [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjy-JOI7cL0AhXS62EKHbtuD0wQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fjournals%2Fjournal-of-differential-geometry%2Fvolume-17%2Fissue-2%2FThree-manifolds-with-positive-Ricci-curvature%2F10.4310%2Fjdg%2F1214436922.full&usg=AOvVaw1Q8Z_FgOvncHlxj0Q5JhfE). I'm working in section 9 on Preserving Positive Ricci Curvature. In theorem 9.4, I need to show if $\epsilon Rg_{ij}\le R_{ij}$ at $t=0$, then the bound continuous remains.

From his proof,  Dr Hamilton uses the contraction of $\epsilon Rg_{ij}\le R_{ij}$ to show $2\lambda\le \mu+\nu$ to show the null-eigenvector assumption and follow with the tensor maximum principle.  The proof is correct but I have a question.

**Question:**  $\epsilon Rg_{ij}\le R_{ij}$ is true for any entry, then we should have the ineqaulity $$\mu,\nu\ge \epsilon (\lambda+\nu+\mu)=\lambda$$ Then the $\mu+\nu-2\lambda\ge 0$ will be trivial. Is there any mistake from my proof.

Comment: How did you get the iequality $\epsilon (\lambda+\nu+\mu)=\lambda$?

Comment: Let $M_{ij}=R_{ij}-\epsilon Rg_{ij}$, then consider $M_{11}=0$, implies $\lambda=\epsilon (\lambda+\mu+\nu)$

Comment: Are you suggesting that Hamilton's proof could be simplified? What you say is correct, and present in Hamilton's paper in the two sentences "Now if $R_{ij}\geq\varepsilon Rg_{ij}$ ... so $\mu+\nu-2\lambda\geq 0$." on p.281